# Mailbox permissions changed automatically whm

Tags: permissions, cpanel, whm, webmail

I faced problem for accessing webmail in cpanel. it say user x@x.com don't have authorize to access. after that when i go in WHM and use `Repair Mailbox Permissions` i see some ownership and permissions changed and everything become fine.

Now the problem is after some time it cause problem and show error message again.

`Fixed ownership on /home/x/mail/x.com/support/dovecot-quota: was (501:505), now (501:502)
Fixed permissions on /home/x/mail/x.com/support/dovecot-quota: was (0600), now (0640)`

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your WHM version changes. if you recently do some changes is your WHM version (Updating), you see this kind of error may happen. So it may take some times to fixed.

In the other hand put your IP into cPHulk Brute Force Protection whitelist too.

Comment: I was updating my WHM to new version.Thanks.